# Ergodicity of 2 independent ergodic random processes

Tags: ergodic

I'm wondering if $\{X_i\}$ and $\{Y_i\}$ are 2 independent processes that are ergodic, then would $\{(X_i,Y_i)\}$ be ergodic?

I believe it is the case under the additional assumption that the two processes are either stationary, asymptotically stationary (i.e. $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(T^{-n}E)$ exists) or asymptotically mean stationary (i.e. $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{-1}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}P(T^{-i}E)$ exists). But I haven't been able to figure out a way to prove so.

Edit: By ergodic process, I mean it satisfies $P(E)$ is either 0 or 1 for all invariant events $E$ (those that satisfy $T^{-1}E=E$).

Edit #2: $T$ is the left-shift transformation.

Comment: There are various definitions of "ergodic."  All those listed in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_process) trivially and immediately imply your result without any special assumptions, because all properties (whether ensemble or time averages) of the product process are evaluated component by component.

Comment: Thanks whuber. I'm looking for a formal proof, but the definitions on Wikipedia are vague and insufficient for that.

Comment: Fine--what is *your* definition?  I see you added something in an edit, but what is $T$?  Are you assuming only processes indexed by integers?

Comment: @whuber: Sorry for the confusion. $T$ is the left-shift transformation. And yes, I'm assuming integer-indexed processes.

Comment: @Yair Daon: Thank you Yair. I'm wondering, would all invariant events on (X,Y) be in the form of a cross product of a set on X and a set on Y? If this was true, then I agree with you. Or maybe I misunderstood your reply...

Comment: The answer is no: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1001259/product-of-ergodic-transformations

Comment: hikaru Your question is not clear because you are talking about possibly non-stationnary processes but you are implicitely assuming stationary processes from your definition of ergodicity and the relation with the shift $T$. Anyway my previous link shows the answer is no (for stationnary processes).

Answer (score 2):

The approximation of sets by rectangles does not work in general, i.e. this is not enough to prove ergodicity of a product system.

As pointed out in the other thread
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/196490/ergodicity-of-2-independent-ergodic-random-processes
the result you are looking for is false even for a product of irrational rotations (one of the standard examples in ergodic theory).

Here invariant sets of non-trivial measure are given by thickened diagonals ${(a,a+b): a\in[0,1), b\in[0,\varepsilon)}$ for $\varepsilon>0$. Those diagonal strips can not be approximated well by rectangles and thus ergodicity of the product fails, even though both irrational rotation factors are ergodic.